# Finding the square root of numbers in a range in JavaScript without using Math.sqrt() and Only For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
function getNumbersWithSquareRoots(max) {
  const arrNum = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    arrNum.push(i);
  }
  return arrNum;
}
```

Can Only use JavaScript and for loops or for of or for in along with if else.

This pushes the numbers 0 through 200 into my empty array. What I need my code to do is go through the array and get every number that can be a square root.
For example: if Max = 200, every number in the range of 0 to 200 find each number that have square roots that are integers. The array would return
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16 etc..., till 196 because anything after this is not a square root].
I know that 2 ** 2 is possible for finding square roots.

I have tried even using Math.sqrt()
But I end up with just an array of numbers being squared.

```
function getNumbersWithSquareRoots(max) {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    arrNum.push(Math.sqrt(i));
  }
  return arrNum;
}
```

Comment: So you're looking for integers that are perfect squares? That is, integers whose square roots are also integers?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for integers that are whole numbers. I know that you can have Number.isInteger. But I do not know what else to add to my code to check for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can square each number and check to see if the result is less than the maximum.

```
function getNumbersWithSquareRoots(max) {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    var square = i * i;
    if (square < max) {
        arrNum.push(square);
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
  }
  return arrNum;
}
```

The `else` is only there to break out of the loop once you've gone beyond the maximum.

Comment: `i<max` is a weird condition though. Either put the condition in the `if`, or in the loop, don't use two conditions.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but the restrictions in the question are to only use a for loop and an if/else. If using `sqrt(max)` was allowed, that would be a more natural limit.

Comment: I mean either using `i * i < max` (and dropping the `if`), or just using `true` for the loop condition.

Comment: @Bergi Using `i * i < max` would be computing the square twice. Using `true` for the loop condition is better, but might not be as intuitive to a beginner. (But based on the OP's posted answer, using a `break` wasn't either.)

Answer (score 1):

> This pushes the numbers 0 through 200 into my empty array. What I need my code to do is go through the array and get every number that can be a square root.

No, that's the wrong approach. Don't go through 200 numbers and try to find out which of them is square (has an integer square root). Instead, loop and put only square numbers in the array in the first place! That is much simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without an `if` and without any multiplication:

```js
function getNumbersWithSquareRoots(max) {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (let sq=i=0; (sq+=i+i+1) < max; i++) arrNum.push(sq);
  return arrNum;
}

console.log(getNumbersWithSquareRoots(200))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getNumbersWithSquareRoots(max) {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    var square = i * i;
    if (square < max) {
       arrNum.push(square);
   }
  }
return arrNum;
}
```

This ended up working for my task that I was trying to complete.
Thank you everyone.